# how to create a vb script to open the WP8 Camera Roll folder in Win7 Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, vbscript

I want to open the Camera Roll folder  when I plug in my Windows 8 Phone to my Windows 7 Pro 64bit desktop PC. I can drill down to the folder but 5 folders deep its annoying each time. I am hoping to use this script to do that but it does not work. I am not referring to the Phone correctly or something.

```
dim objShell
set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
objShell.Open("C:\Users\Doug\Desktop\Camera Dump")
objShell.Open("DougWin8Phone\Phone\Pictures\Camera Roll")
objshell.TileVertically
set objShell = nothing
```